# How to get an internal IP address?

Tags: java, sockets, ip, internal

First of all my programming language is Java. I created a simple chat program using sockets. It works pretty good.

I tried it on my computer (localhost) between two terminal instances.

I want to try it out on my laptop, or on another computer. For this I need the client's internal IP address.

How to figure out client's internal IP address using Java?

I specially want to get it out with Java, not using CMD, or something like this. I mean - that's not just a constant string.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, there is a class ***[InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/InetAddress.html)*** that represents IP Adress (and its corresponding host name, in some cases).

For example, let's get my IP address and my host name:

```java
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress i = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println(i);                  // host name and IP address
            System.out.println(i.getHostName());    // name
            System.out.println(i.getHostAddress()); // IP address only
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output (in my case):

> LLEITE/192.168.1.100
>   LLEITE
>   192.168.1.100

Comment: Someone told me I need to "Open a port in my modem" (I'm not sure I write in english correctly).. do you know that is he talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("IP of my system is := "+ownIP.getHostAddress());`
```

Comment: Someone told me I need to "Open a port in my modem" (I'm not sure I write in english correctly).. do you know that is he talking about?

Comment: @iLoveC I think this link may help you.http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/223583

Comment: thank you very much, but I'm using linux fedora .. Is this tutorial still effective for me?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need open ports on the server machine or on the client machine?